# Mongo DB Check nested object field, create and add unique value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Document collection have nested Object called 'xxx', I wanted to add new field if not exist also assign new UUID for that field.

```
{_id: '000', vgr: {tp: 'a', en: 'b'}},

{_id: '000', vgr: {tp: 'c', en: 'd'}}
```

Above one is my sample collection, Now I want to add new field in 'vgr' object called 'id' (UUID), also I need to check if object have 'id' field or not.

Comment: *Document collection have nested Object called 'xxx'* = what does that mean ? All you wanted to do is to add a new field(`id`) inside `vgr` object, Only for docs where it's not already present ? Also is that UUID value generated in code & passed into to query for `id` field or do you want it to be created by mongoDB ? If yes what is your MongoDB version ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
db.collection.updateMany({"vgr.id": {$exists: false}}, {$set: {"vgr.id": UUID()}})
```

The first parameter is your `filter`: you are looking for documents which don't already contain the nested property `id` in the `vgr` object.

The second parameter is where you add the nested `id` field to the filtered documents.